# Can SpeechRecognition Package (https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/) work offline?

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I am creating a Speech-to-text converter and I need a package/lib that works offline. Does the SpeechRecognition Module work offline?

I have tried it and in my case I got no reply from the module. So my assumption would be that it doesn't work offline.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the `pocketsphinx` library. You can get it [here](https://pypi.org/project/pocketsphinx/)
or
use `pip install pocketsphinx`
It works offline!

Comment: Hi @Learner, thanks for the reply. I will check it out.
Is there an official link/webpage where it is clearly stated that the SpeechRecognition library does not work offline?

Comment: Speech recognition _does_ work offline; provided you use an offline speech recognition package. Pocketsphinx is one of these. https://realpython.com/python-speech-recognition/#picking-a-python-speech-recognition-package

Comment: Great, you answered my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How [@Sid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11915854/sid) said u can use the `pocketsphinx` libary, but I recommend you to use [Vosk](https://github.com/alphacep/vosk-api).

Vosk also works offline and is compatible with many [languages](https://alphacephei.com/vosk/models). It outputs the spoken text live and works reasonably well.
I've been using it for over a year and I'm still very happy with it, it also runs on the Raspberry Pi without any performance problems.